# How to run git command remotely?

Tags: ruby, git, remote-server

How to run git command on remote computer? I want to run `git show` or `git log` on remote computer. how to run command similar to subversion? what is your solution?
Update:
For example I have a server that can connect to it by ssh or over http protocol and my source code saved on that server. I want to access to change set detail programmatically by ruby via git command without cloning.

Comment: please clarify or show examples what you mean by "running on a remote computer, similar to subversion"

Comment: do you want to do it programmatically  or just to see manually, for former Erik has already suggested to use ssh, for latter case the most easy way will be login to remote server using windows remote desktop or Remmina in linux and execute the command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you literally want to run the command remotely, do it over SSH:

```
ssh username@host "cd my/repo/path && git show"
```